# Add user control on a button click from another user control

Tags: c#, wpf

i have two user control and when i click on a button from the first user control ,another user control shows up :
The first user control is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Navigateur.Presentation.UserControlWork
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour ListeBlanche.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ListeBlanche : UserControl
    {
        public ListeBlanche()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReferenceParent.ParentServiceClient wcfParent = new ServiceReferenceParent.ParentServiceClient();
            bool existe = await wcfParent.LogInAsync(textmail.Text, textpass.Text);
            if (existe)
            {
                //grid.Children.Remove(this);
                //this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                //ParentControl parmain = new ParentControl();
                //parmain.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                //parmain.
            }
            else
            {
                Popup1.IsOpen = true;

            }

        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
            ParentControl parmain = new ParentControl();
            main.gridMain.Children.Add(parmain);
            parmain.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

        }


    }
}
```

and when i click on "Button_Click_2",ParentControl shows up but it never shows.

Fullscreen:
this is the ParenControl xaml code:

```
`<UserControl x:Class="Navigateur.Presentation.UserControlWork.ParentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="586.194" Height="316.418">
    <Grid Background="#FF65B4EC" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="586" Background="#FF5ACAFF" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Label Content="Création de votre compte parent" Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="155" Background="#FF65B4EC" FontWeight="Black">
                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-0.376"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>
        </Canvas>
        <Label Content="Nom Compte" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Pseudo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.006"/>
        <Label Content="Prénom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Nom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="323,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.2,0.471"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,132,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="323,191,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Monsieur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Madame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,245,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="323,245,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Button Content="Annuler" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="23"/>
        <Button Content="Suivant" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="297,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>`
```

and this is my main window xaml code:

```
    <Window x:Name="wndmain" x:Class="Navigateur.Presentation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:auth="clr-namespace:Navigateur.Presentation.UserControlWork"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="317" Width="586.194" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <auth:ListeBlanche ClickedInUserControl="OnClickedInUserControl"></auth:ListeBlanche>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `main` is a new instance of `MainWindow` but not the parent instance of the user control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use a RoutedEvent in your UserControl to get this to work.

So change your click event in your usercontrol to:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler ClickedInUserControl;
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if (ClickedInUserControl != null)
        {
            ClickedInUserControl(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }         

}
```

Then in you MainWindow's xaml add this too the UserControl:

```
ClickedInUserControl="OnClickedInUserControl"
```

And then add the event handler on your mainwindow's codebehind

```
private void OnClickedInUserControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ParentControl parmain = new ParentControl();
    this.gridMain.Children.Add(parmain);
    parmain.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    // also remove the original usercontrol from the grid and collapse it's vilisibilty
}
```

Also, I would highly recommend that you look into using Commands rather than Events for this kind of thing, but I used events because that's what you were working with.

Comment: Thank you @safetyOtter, it worked but i need my user control to be displayed in full screen. How can i do this???
Also can you specify more about using commands( give me tutorials..)
Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help!  By fullscreen do you mean you wantthe control to fill its container or do you mean you want the app to be fill your windows screen? Either way I'll need to see more of your xaml.  As for commands, here's the tutorial I started with [Understanding Routed Events and Commands In WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx) but I've since moved to the MVVM Light framework for new projects and [here's the article that helped me there.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)

Comment: By Fullscreen i mean that my main window is on full screen mode and i need that my user control fiil it.
Once again i really appreciate your cooperation.this site is like a heaven for me...